# Not resizing downloaded images correctly

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have added a table view, and I am display image in the cells. I have also added this code:

So that the cells resize depending on the image.

When I launch my app though, I get this :

[![enter image description here][1]]

And the images do not load untill I start scrolling...If I scroll down half the page then go back to the top, I get this: Which is correct

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Any ideas? I have researched on google and tried the odd solution for the older versions of Xcode, But nothing seems to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is already downloaded and resident in your cache when you pass the post to the cell them the image view will have an image and therefore an intrinsic content size. This all allows the table view to calculate the required layout.

If the image needs to be downloaded then the image view won't have an image and will size to zero because there is no intrinsic content size other than that.

If your images are all the same size then you can supply a placeholder image while waiting for the download and the cell will size appropriately.

Note also that you aren't updating the cell when the image has downloaded. When you do this you do need to check that the cell hasn't been reused (or you'll be showing the wrong image). If you don't have a placeholder or can't guarantee the image size then you will also need to ask the table view to update.

Comment: Perhaps you already have a callback done by `self.image.value = image`, looks like reactive kit usage... So you accept what you have now or you add placeholder images (or pre-download all the images).

Comment: i may pre-download some. most apps don't and instead use a placeholder or just leave an empty space

Comment: when you set the post and configure the cell

Comment: adding it at the beginning of cell for row is fine, that's where you configure the cell with the post

Comment: so what is your image named circle ?

Comment: add the placeholder there, ensure it's a reasonable size image

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  your `post.downloadImage()` and `post.fetchLikes()` should callback, and in callback, should reload cell in mainThread. hope it help.